# Best practice for cloning a private Github repo from a Dockerfile

Tags: github, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile. I clone the private repo by asking a github personal token as argument [with the appropriate privileges].

Is this the best practice?

Does this practice pose any security threat for the TOKEN?

I saw that some people use SSH keys, but I think is a lot of extra work compared to this solution.

```
# Starting from Python 2.7 base image
FROM python:2.7

# Update PIP
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install GIT
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install git -y



# Set environmental vars
ARG GH_TOKEN=WRONG_GITHUB_TOKEN

# Adding the whole project from the repo to the container
RUN git clone https://$GH_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/org/repo.git /repo

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /repo

# Install dependencies via pip
RUN pip install -r dependencies.txt

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /repo/folder

# Run a command for the container
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```